# Typescript fails to check nested object on function return type

Tags: typescript, typechecking

Typescript fails to check on return type if it is a nested object. Consider the code below, Typescript will not send out errors even if the result variable in function A is clearly not matched to the Output type.

```
interface Input {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

interface Output {
  c: Omit<Input, 'a'>;
  d: string;
}

function A(input: Input): Output {
  const result = { c: {a: 'aaa', b: 3}, d: 'okay' };

  // Expect to have an error since the result is not matched to Output
  // but there's not errors
  return result;
}

function B(input: Input): Output {
  const result = "{ c: {a: 'aaa', b: 3}, d: 'okay' }";

  // Work as expected
  return result;
}

// But access a property will give us error. 
const test = A({ a: 'a', b: 3 });
test.c.a
```

[Playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FczIN4BQyycAXMgM5hSgDmA3EcgEbkhYC2z0jAvgQVCRYiFAHkc2XIWIJyYjsDAAedFIA0yAORwtAPkbEAJuSo0QDAvwIwsIBGGAB7EMgCCAClBTyanAEp5SRx8JgQXKmQoCAosABtcAF58ZDl8Mm04LK1NVmQAZl5NE20nAGs4AE8tZF5GJgB6BuQAUQAPDAgHZDAnZAALOAA3FGgoJyhKUCQomPjcYApkECdcDjgwBH6evokwKSZosCwoV2jYhL4BW3tHF2QAIS9MHF8XsEDkPalQ2Qjcc7zZDJABEeFS5DwGR02Vy5EKxXIWnKVRqvBB9WITWQAHUJmUSEsIB0upAjIcIMdTrMLmArgRsQ8QogkBQlnBkBhxp0oGBKsgAO7AOJxZC0YAjZBYIlQcZQAB0yAI4RAkUgkWSnnB0N0cIKvH8jHVYHlCHlcCAA).

Any idea why this happened?

If we explicitly told Typescript that `const result: Output = ...`, it will give us errors. But I'm not sure this is a good practice or not. Is there another way to make it work as expected?

Comment: Why do you have quotes around the value in `const result = "{ c: {a: 'aaa', b: 3}, d: 'okay' }";`? (And I'm sure you didn't a second ago, did you...?)

Comment: It was to test if typescript performs type checking here. In function A, I return an object and in function B, I return a string. Typescript did show errors in function B since String doesn't match to Output type. But when it comes to an object, Typescript didn't show any errors.

Comment: Yeah, I got `A` and `B` confused.

Comment: My bad. It could name in a clearer way haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea why this happened?
>
> If we explicitly told Typescript that `const result: Output = ...`, it will give us errors....

TypeScript applies more strict type checking to object *literals* than it does to other expressions (including variable references). In this case, the "more strict" part when you explicitly provide a type for `result` is an [*excess property check*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).¹ That's a pragmatic check done because typically that's a programmer error, but in the *general* case excess properties are okay (because the shape of the object still matches the target type, it's just a subtype because it has more properties).

You also get the error if you do the return directly:

```typescript
function A(input: Input): Output {
    return { c: {a: 'aaa', b: 3}, d: 'okay' };
}
```

though (subjectively) I generally prefer your original code because it's easier to debug.

It's largely a matter of style, but I would solve the problem by doing this as a general practice when possible:

```typescript
function A(input: Input) {
//                      ^−−−− No return type annotation
    const result: Output = { c: {a: 'aaa', b: 3}, d: 'okay' };
//                ^−−−−−−−−−− Explicit type

    return result; // <−−−−−− TypeScript infers return type
}
```

Note that the function's return type is still `Output`, it's just that TypeScript inferred it from the `return` rather than our specifying it explicitly in two places.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgA4FczIN4BQyxycAXMgM5hSgDmA3ESQEYUhYC2L0TAvgQKhIsRCgDyObLkIlkCCuM7AwAHnTSANMgDkcHQD4mcgCYVqtEIwICCMLCARhgAexDIAggApQ0ihpwASnwCAHpQuUio6IA9QCQiBLjkADkXZCgIMCwodzAATwwUOBAQFzA4ZzdmYgQ3anSISiwAGzBFKRxkAF58eQo8cl04YZ1tNmQAZj5tM10XAGs4PJ1kPiZw6M3keMTdhOQAUQAPDGbgBBVkfMLBOQysnIam1oZkDdU9pIAVAogAZQQtAwuFAMGglAaD1yvxsgg2AHFgAA3CAESDUAB0CAxcAIQA)

---

¹ As I write this in April 2021, the TypeScript documentation is going through a major rewrite, and the linked page is listed as "deprecated" with a new to "the new page," but the new page doesn't yet describe excess property checks. Hopefully that's fixed soon.

Comment: Ah got it! Super thanks for pointing out the "excess property check" for me. I'm not aware of this. Also, thanks for the suggested solution. Very helpful. Thank you!!